# Unexpected behaviour of private methods in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created some simple class by this example https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html with private and public methods, but I've got an error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'somePrivateMethod' of undefined`.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() {}

  somePublicMethod() {
    this.somePrivateMethod();
  }

  private somePrivateMethod() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I just call `myService.somePublicMethod` from my component and do not use `somePrivateMethod`.

I call it in my component like these:

```
   constructor(
      private myService: MyService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      inputs.map(this.myService.somePublicMethod)
    }
```

I tired to solve it like this:

```
   constructor(
      private myService: MyService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
      const myMethod = this.myService.somePublicMethod.bind(this)
      inputs.map(myMethod)
    }
```

But anyway I've got the same error. Where is the problem?

Comment: Is this the only place you are calling the method, or is it being used some where else also?

Comment: @Venomy I've updated my post. Yes, it's the only place where I use my private method

Comment: What happens if, in your component, you just call `this.myService.somePublicMethod()` instead of the `inputs.map...`?

Comment: @Venomy oops, now it works

Comment: Glad to hear that! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: @Venomy anyway can't understand how to solve it. I've tried `this.myService.somePublicMethod.bind(this)` but it throws the same error

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `inputs.map` ?

Comment: @Venomy apply this.myService.somePublicMethod on each element of `inputs`

Comment: `inputs.map(this.myService.somePublicMethod.bind(this.myService))`, or simpler: `inputs.map(input => this.myService.somePublicMethod(input))`. This will create an array of undefined, though, since the method doesn't return anything.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks a lot!